# c# implementing a bucket sort algorithm

Tags: c#, sorting, bucket-sort

Good evening everyone here! I created a bucket sort algorithm, but it throws me an error that index is out of range. Could you please tell me where is the problem? I can't find the solution by myself, that's why I'm asking for your help

```
public int[] Sort(int[] unsortedSequence)
        {
            List<List<int>> buckets = new List<List<int>>();
            InitializeBuckets(buckets);
            Scatter(unsortedSequence, buckets);
            int i = 0;
            foreach (List<int> bucket in buckets)
            {
                int[] arr = bucket.ToArray();
                InsertionSort(arr);
                foreach (int d in arr)
                {
                    unsortedSequence[i++] = d;
                }
            }
            return unsortedSequence;
        }
        private static void Scatter(int[] array, List<List<int>> buckets)
        {
            foreach (int value in array)
            {
                int bucketNumber = GetBucketNumber(value);
                buckets[bucketNumber].Add(value);
            }
        }
        private static void InsertionSort(int[] array)
        {
            int j;
            int temp;

            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                j = i;
                while (j > 0 && array[j] < array[j - 1])
                {
                    temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j - 1];
                    array[j - 1] = temp;
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }
        private static int GetBucketNumber(int value)
        {
            int val = value * 10;

            return val;
        }

        private static void InitializeBuckets(List<List<int>> buckets)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                List<int> a = new List<int>();
                buckets.Add(a);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code to find out where you're going outside the bounds of the array. An *index out of bounds* error is only caused when you exceed the bounds of the array, and you can step through the code to find your logic error that's causing that to happen. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is an excellent time to learn; it really isn't difficult to step through the code to solve this sort of problem.

Comment: I can't find the problem

Comment: Then look harder. Its been a whole 4 minutes since I posted my last comment - hardly enough time to make an effort to step through the coe in the debugger. At least make an effort to do something. Less than 4 minutes effort is not even worth mentioning. Use the debugger - it's going to be the most useful tool you'll ever have in your programming toolkit, and you need to learn to use it. Start now. The error message tells you where the problem occurs and what the invalid index value is, which is more than enough information to start debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what logic you did for sorting this but I got why you are getting index out of range error.

**Error in Code**

You are creating 10 buckets and now you are trying to generate bucket number by multiplying current value or array with 10.

For example, if your current value of array is 2 then generated bucket number will be 20. You got only 10 buckets so `Scatter()` method will give you error.

```
 private static void Scatter(int[] array, List<List<int>> buckets)
 {
     foreach (int value in array)
     {
         int bucketNumber = GetBucketNumber(value);
         buckets[bucketNumber].Add(value); // ERROR HERE
     }
 }
```

**SOLUTION**

Actually, there is problem with `GetBucketNumber()` method. You should use remainder not multiplication. Change method with following.

```
private static int GetBucketNumber(int value)
{
    int val = value % 10;
    return val;
}
```

**You must do**

Try to solve your problem with hard attempts before you ask for help. Run your program on paper first I mean confirm your logic before you start coding. Have faith in you and give enough time to your attempts. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer, I want to strongly suggest that you always make a good faith attempt at solving a problem first before seeking outside help. I don't necessarily think you didn't try, but this problem was easily identified by stepping through the debugger.

If that's an aspect of coding you're not too familiar with, I strongly recommend making it a priority to learn - it will only make you a better developer in the long run.

The problem is occurring in the `Scatter` method at this point:

`int bucketNumber = GetBucketNumber(value);
buckets[bucketNumber].Add(value);`

The exception occurs because `GetBucketNumber` multiplies the input by 10, but you're using that multiplied value as the index for `buckets`.

Comment: well, I did know where the problem was because the error outputed the incorrect lines. but I didn't know how to solve this problem that's why I came here. This is a new language for me and It is possible that I don't know basic stuff